# ${ y= \sqrt{x^2 +e^{-x}} \cos^2(\frac{ \pi }{3}+2x) - \frac{ \ln{(1+2x)}}{\sqrt{2^x+3}} }$. Find the slope of normal line

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> ${ y= \sqrt{x^2 +e^{-x}} \cos^2(\frac{ \pi }{3}+2x)- \frac{ \ln{(1+2x)}}{\sqrt{2^x+3}}}$
> . Find the slope of a normal **line that passes through $(0,1)$**.

I'm currently learning Calculus $1$ at university. This problem was given on a midterm.

The first step I did was differentiate $y$, which would give me the slope of a tangent line, from there I would usually find the slope of a normal line by taking it's negative reciprocal. But how do I find the normal line in this example? I'm very lost on how to approach this problem, both algebraically and geometrically. I'll be very thankful for any insight.

EDIT: I've verified and the problem asks for the equation of a normal line that passes through the point $(0,1)$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The curve passes through $(0,1/4)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine that the point is in fact $(0,\frac 14)$ instead of $(0,1)$. This way the curve actually passes through the point.

As it was mentioned in other posts, you just need to compute the derivative $y'(0)$. It is not the simplest derivative, but still you just need to apply the rules to get to the expression posted by @DonAntonio. This way you get the slope of the tangent line, which is $-\frac 98 - \sqrt{3}$. The slope of the normal line is then given by

$$
m = -\frac{1}{-\frac 98 - \sqrt{3}} = \frac{8}{9+8 \sqrt{3}}.
$$

**[edit]**
In the unlikely event that the examiner wanted students to find the slope of a normal line to the curve that passes through $(0,1)$, this is how you could do it:

The line would be normal to the curve in some point $x_0$ and would satisfy the equation $y = 1 -\frac{x}{y'(x_0)}$. Now, this line must intersect the original curve at $x = x_0$, so $y(x_0) = 1-\frac{x_0}{y'(x_0)}$. This last equality provides a nonlinear equation that would allow to compute $x_0$ and the slope of the normal line, which could be $\approx 0.232369$. By the way, the solution is not unique, as you can see in the plot below.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How would we approach this problem if the point $(0,1)$ meant that the normal line should pass at that point? As I've said in my edit.

Comment: @Ebrin There was just a typo in the midterm... If the intention was to find the slope of a normal line that passes through $(0,1)$, the question is so badly formulated that I refuse to believe this is the case.

Comment: I've translated this problem to English, the problem was not well formulated in my native language too. Turns out (after checking with classmates) it asks for the slope of a normal line that passes through the point $(0,1)$. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Ebrin Were students allowed to use a calculator? It seems to me that it must be solved numerically.

Comment: we have access to regular calculators, but not the scientific ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight. I have to ask, how would I solve the "nonlinear equation"? Cause I don't know how to solve an equation that complex, is there an easy way?  The way we get $y'(x_0)$ would just be plugging a point $x_0$ instead of $x$ in the equation DonAntonio provided, am I correct? Solving that seems like a nightmare.

Comment: @Ebrin Yes, when the point is on the curve (and is given), it is just a matter of computing $y'(x_0)$ in terms of $x_0$ and $y(x_0)$, like DonAntonio did. Regarding the solution of the nonlinear equation, there are standard numerical methods, like Newton's method, that can give you the solution, within a certain accuracy, in just a few iterations.

Comment: Thanks, you've been extremely helpful!

Answer (score 2):

$$ y= \sqrt{x^2 +e^{-x}} \cos^2(\frac{ \pi }{3}+2x)- \frac{ \ln{(1+2x)}}{\sqrt{2^x+3}}\implies$$

$$y'=\frac{2x-e^{-x}}{2\sqrt{x^2+e^{-x}}}\,\cos^2\left(\frac\pi3+2x\right)-2\sqrt{x^2+e^{-x}}\,\sin\left(2\left(\frac\pi3+2x\right)\right)-$$

$$-\frac{\frac{2\sqrt{2^x+3}}{1+2x}-\ln(1+2x)\cdot\frac{2^{x-1}\ln2}{\sqrt{2^x+3}}}{2^x+3}$$

The monster above is the derivative of $\;y\;$ at any point where it is differentiable. Evaluate now $\;y'(0)\;$ (you don't need to do any simplifaction) and afterwards just evaluate $\;-\cfrac1{y'(0)}\;$, which is the slope of the normal line at $\;x=0\;$ ...

By the way, and just as Pierre commented: your curve doesn't pass through the point $\;(0,1)\;$ , so perhaps the answer should be "this cannot be done" ...

Comment: You mean $-\frac{1}{y'(0)}$.

Comment: @DonAntonio The curve does not pass through $(0,1)$.

Comment: @A-levelStudent Of course. I needed to separate more the minus sign. Thanks

Comment: @Pie Indeed so, Pierre. He'll have to sort that problem out by himself.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Also what do you mean by the 2 $-$ signs in your 2nd and 3rd lines of working?

Comment: @A-levelStudent Continuation of line, certainly.

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean at the end of the 2nd line and beginning of the 3rd line.

Comment: @A-levelStudent So did I...

Comment: @DonAntonio Agreed!

Comment: Doesn't a minus and a minus make a plus?

Comment: @A-levelStudent Try to understand: is usual notation in notes, books and etc. When your line end and your are writing a formula, you just cut tje formula in an operation sign )usually plus or minus, and pass to the next line repeating the sing. Like  $$3-1-1=3-1-$$$$-1$$

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm sorry to have bothered you, I've simply never encountered that before, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A tangent and a nomal have gradients (or slope if you prefer) that when multiplied together equal $-1$. This means that if the grdaient of the tangent at a given point is $m$ then the grdaient of the normal at the same point will be the negative reciprocal of it ie $-\frac{1}{m}$. So, once you've fpund the grdaient of the tangent at the guven point, which can be found by differentiation as you have done, then we can write the equation of the normal as
$$-\frac{1}{m}=\frac{y-1}{x-0}=\frac{y-1}{x}$$
where $m$ is the grdaient of the tangent at that point.

I hope that helps!